# Cannot SSH into Azure Windows Server VM

Tags: windows, azure, ssh, virtual-machine

I created a new Virtual Machine in Azure. (Windows Server 2016 Datacenter Server Core)

The VM creation process allowed me to enable SSH access (and I did):
[Image of VM Creation Wizard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8qvD.png)

However I find myself **unable** to establish a SSH connection to the Windows Server.

I learned that in situations like this, it is sometimes necessary to reset the "configuration password":
["Reset Password" for VM](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO6DA.png)

This action allowed me to successfully use the "troubleshoot the connection" tool (built into Azure) to "stage" a SSH connection (from my IP to the Azure VM). However I *still* find myself unable to establish a SSH connection. (The connection continues to "time out".)

[Image of Inbound Network Rules](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QDsAl.png)

[Image of Azure "Connection troubleshooter"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pgdN.png)

Any ideas?

Comment: It would appear as though the SSH Server service is not (currently) installed on this server. I am having difficulty installing the service. https://imgur.com/a/Yvyyuco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to follow these instructions to manually install the sshd service:
https://365adviser.com/powershell/install-use-openssh-windows-powershell-core-remoting-via-ssh/

It's worth noting that Step #2 refers to a depreciated GitHub project. As such I needed to tweak the URI. I also needed to append the the `-UseBasicParsing` option. Here is the final result:

`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri http://mengelsen.000webhostapp.com/shared-items/OpenSSH-Win64.zip -UseBasicParsing -OutFile openssh.zip`